# MS SQL vs Oracle Order By

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm confronted i guess with the oracle nulls problem - not sure - where Oracle is giving me a different result than MS SQL. The column (Day) I am trying to order is a date/time column and the id column is just a varchar:

[image]

Here, on the left is the result the way I want it - but with the same SQL with Oracle I'm getting a different(read: wrong) result. As far as I've looked up in the internet is that it has something to do with the fact that it cannot find C IDs on 2015-01-01 and 2015-01-02 - thats why it pushes the sole C result in the beginning. Whats more strange is the fact that it does not even order it right -

MS SQL Server:

```
2015-01-01
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
2015-01-03
2015-01-03
```

Oracle:

```
2015-01-03
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
```

->The query is quite simple:

```
select id,day from dayidtable order by day
```

In my Java Web app - how can I make sure to use the same SQL that caters for both MS SQL and Oracle databases? Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

I have one request please ! I know the result of oracle does not make any sense "theoretically" - but thats what i get - before this question gets bloated with "not possible" answers so i request you people to answer only if you have any idea or a hunch. Thanks alot.

Anyone?

UPDATE:

if i use the following sql - the oracle results work fine now:

```
select id,day from dayidtable order by day,id
```

but the question remains why doesn't it sort with only "day" like MS SQL?

Comment: can you post your query and java code?

Comment: the query is quite simple but the same results above: select id,day from dayidtable order by day

Comment: What are the datatypes of the columns? What is the query you are using? What is `01-03`? Is it **1st March** or is it **3rd January**?

Comment: @LalitKumarB Excellent point! - However, either way, `01-03` should come after `01-01`.

Comment: Your results don't make sense.  `Order by` works correctly in both databases.

Comment: @gordon-linoff the results are as shown in the picture - i'm getting crazy with this oracle trying the same queries again and again but i get these results which don't make any sense

Comment: I'm confident you are not making something up to fool us, but as @GordonLinoff said: What we can see in your question does not make sense. So the issue must be something else which is not included in your question. Can you post your `CREATE TABLE` statements and the `INSERT`s, and possibly check the localization configurations of your DBs.

Comment: can you maybe give me a suggestion what to look for in the CREATE TABLE/INSERT/localization -  as i don't have access anymore to tht specific db - but a hint what to look for would be helpful thanks

Comment: The problem is not related with null values (you don't have) or with the number of dates related with C value (ID is not in the order by).  As far as I know it is not a localization issue (it only affects dates in a 24 hour interval, and between 1 and 3 there at least 24h + 1 second). No matter if your column in Oracle is DATE or VARCHAR2, trust me, the fact is that this is not the Oracle result for this query and data. Then there are only two reasonable answers: 1) your program is sending a query without ORDER BY clause, 2) your program is modifying the order of the result returned by oracle.

Comment: Is there an index on the Day column that could be corrupt? Try `order by 2` instead of `order by day` because `day` is a reserved word. Try executing the same query directly in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer. I have to agree with the commenters above. It is not an Oracle issue.

Comment: thanks for the replies again - as strange as it sounds the results that i have above in the picture are an exact represantation from SQL TALK (oracle results) query and ms sql server studios (ms sql results) .... that means the program has no play in this ...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have same behaviour depending the database you can implement your own comparator in `Java` side to ensure your sorting.

```
class myComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {
   public int compare(MyClass ob1, MyClass ob2) {
       return ob1.getDay().compareTo(ob2.getDay());  // invert to reverse order
   }   
}
```

Comment: thanks but i think thats not a feasible solution with regards to a possible only sql based solution

Comment: @owsata simply read comments in the question... there are lot of variables in your *simple query* that you don't explain. `ORDER BY` works ok, so your date format, configuration, locale... there are a lot of thinks can can cause this wrong behaviour